# Guardian.Plug.sign_in/2 to session storage instead of cookies?

Tags: cookies, elixir, phoenix-framework, session-storage, ueberauth

During authentication, Guardian.Plug.sign_in(conn, user) is storing session token in cookies by default. Let's say i have a field that tells if the user wants to be remembered or not. If not, how can i store session token in session storage (so it gets discarded on closing browser's window) instead of cookies?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remember me functionality in Phoenix using Guardian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097955/remember-me-functionality-in-phoenix-using-guardian)

Comment: There are two distinct mechanisms and two different sets of functions to do that. Please don't start new questions here, just read Guardian's doc more carefully.